# Getting configure command of php

Tags: installation, php, command-line, install-from-source, configure

I am using an ubutnu OS, I have installed LAMP stack using "tasksel", I am not able to find the "Configure Command" while I am going through phpinfo. But , in the same OS I am able to see the "Configure Command" only if I am compiling the php from source. Is anyone can explain how the tasksel hiding their "Configure Command" and how to find their "Configure Command".

With 
Regards 
Dipu R

---

I have installed two LAMP stack in two different machine runs on Ubuntu. One LAMP is installed using "tasksel"(an installer)  other one I installed from source. I have created a page in LAMP(created using task)
I have created page in both LAMP and called phpinfo()(this functions lists information about installed php). In the LAMP(installed from source), showing "configure command" entry in phpinfo table, but in the same time "configure command" is missing(or not displaying) in the other LAMP(installed using tasksel). I wish to know how the "tasksel" hiding the "configure command", also wish to know is there any chance to view it.

Comment: Hello Dan, thank you, see below I have explained.

Comment: @DipuR you should be able to edit your own questoin to add additional requested information, rather than post as an answer (which you shouldn't do for comments).

Answer (score 1):

The configure information is deliberately omitted from Ubuntu's binary PHP packages, because it's different for each build of the package anyway. Note that the configure line does not tell you which PHP extensions are enabled and disabled, as they are usually available in separate packages.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/516061) for more information.

Since you don't say what you want the information for, it's hard to suggest what you should do instead. If you still need advice on that, please ask a new question about whatever it is you're really trying to achieve.